# button hover css wordpress issue

Tags: css

I am trying to write CSS for a button that changes color on mouse-over from:

1. white background to black background
2. black text to white text

Can anyone help?

The CSS I wrote (not working as required):

```css
.wpbc-payment-form .btn, .wpbc-payment-form .button, .booking_form_div .btn, .booking_form_div .button, .booking_form_div .submit, .booking_form_div .button-secondary {
    border-color: #377ec4;
    border-radius:50px;
    color: white;!important
    background: black;!important
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 156px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
}

.wpbc-payment-form .btn, .wpbc-payment-form .button, .booking_form_div .btn, .booking_form_div .button, .booking_form_div .submit, .booking_form_div .button-secondary:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background: black;
    color:white;
}
```

button html:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" onclick="mybooking_submit(this.form,1,'en_US');">Book Now</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hover styling is only applied to :

`.booking_form_div .button-secondary`.

All other buttons in the statement (before this) will get `background: black` and other styles.

You want to add the styles individually on hover like:

```css
.b1, .b2{
  width: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background : yellow;
}

.b1:hover,.b2:hover{
  background : green;
}
```

```html
<button class="b1">X</button>
<button class="b2">Y</button>
```